# if function not working VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

```
If (Year(n) - Year(d) >= 1) Then
    MsgBox "Latest Fiscal Year Data is" & dd & "Days," & md & "Months," & yd & "Years Old"
    Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.Italic = True
    Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.Bold = True
    Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.FontStyle = Arial

End If
```

Text Color turns to blue but other commands like italic bold are not executed

Comment: What happens if you select the cell manually and make the changes manually using the ribbon commands?

Comment: ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 1).Font.Name = "Arial"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.FontStyle = Arial
```

to this:

```
Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.Name = "Arial"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the first line on your code, and add this line:

```
Option Explicit
```

Now try to run your code.

You will get an error, because the variable `Arial` is not defined.

This will hint you, that it should probably be:

```
Sheets("" & Filename).Cells(5, y2).Font.Name = "Arial"
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

Assuming you've declared all your variables correctly and the only problem you're having is that the cell isn't formatting as expected.

- As pointed out already - `Arial` needs to be `"Ariel"`
- Set the font as the first line of formatting.  You add your bold, italic and blue formatting and then set it to Ariel which removes the bold & italic setting.
  **EDIT:**  My mistake - it's because you're using `.Font.FontStyle = "Arial"`.  The change in `FontStyle` removes the bold & italic.  Use `.Font.Name = "Arial"` to keep previously applied formatting.
- Check you haven't any conditional formatting set on that cell as it will override any other formatting you give it.

Aside from that - I'd suggest updating your `FileName` variable to `SheetName` - nothing wrong with `FileName`, you could use `Purple_Rock_Lobber` if you wanted and Excel wouldn't care but it would confuse humans when the code is revisited in a couple of years time.
Also not sure why you've got double quotes infront of `FileName`?